# django project_form is not valid?

Tags: python, django, forms

I have been trying to implement a way to post a project post where the user can upload multiple images. The multiple image upload works but posting the post itself does not work.

I am not sure what to do with the project_form.

It is not valid even tho the fields have correct values.

My code is:

views.py

```
class CreateProjectsView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        p_photos = P_Images.objects.all()
        #project_form = ProjectsForm(initial=self.initial)
        project_form = ProjectsForm
        context = {
            'p_photos': p_photos,
            'project_form': project_form,
        }
        return render(self.request, 'projects/forms.html', context)

    def post(self, request):
        project_form = ProjectsForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        p_formset = P_ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        # Checks if the project_form is valid before save
        if project_form.is_valid():
            instance = project_form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = request.user
            instance.save()

        # Checks if multiple image upload is valid before save
        if p_formset.is_valid(): 
        #if project_form.is_valid() and p_formset.is_valid():   
            #instance = project_form.save(commit=False)
            #instance.user = request.user
            #instance.save()
            images = p_formset.save(commit=False)
            images.save()

            data = {
                'is_valid': True, 
                'name': images.p_file.name, 
                'url': images.p_file.url
            }

        else:
            data = {
                'is_valid': False,
            }

        return JsonResponse(data)
```

forms.html

```
<form action="{% url 'create_post:retrieve_projects' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    {% csrf_token %}  

    {% for hidden in project_form.hidden_fields %}
    {{ hidden }}
    {% endfor %}

    {% for field in project_form %}
    {{ field.errors }}
    {{ field }} <br />
    {% endfor %}

    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

Comment: So I actually found a fix for this. The issue is actually in the html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the form is not valid, you should provide a way for the user to correct their errors and resubmit the form.  Perhaps something like this:

```
    if project_form.is_valid():
        instance = project_form.save(commit=False)
        instance.user = request.user
        instance.save()

    else:
        return render(request, 'project_form.html', {'form': project_form})
```

Comment: It still is not working. Even if you put the right values and files it still is not valid. I was thinking if I maybe I can fix my project_form in my get() maybe it will work. I think I am not doing it correct in my get(). But I do not know what to do

Comment: Well, what errors does the form display?  (You are displaying the form errors in your page template, yes?)

Comment: It doesn't post any errors. Only that nothing is happening. And I do not know how to display form errors in my template, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

So I actually found a fix for this.

The issue is in the forms.html
I changed the "create_post:retrieve_projects" to "create_post:create_projects" in my form section.

forms.html

```
<form action="{% url 'create_post:create_projects' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    {% csrf_token %}  

    {% for hidden in project_form.hidden_fields %}
    {{ hidden }}
    {% endfor %}

    {% for field in project_form %}
    {{ field.errors }}
    {{ field }} <br />
    {% endfor %}

    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```